Find the length of the chord of a circumcircle

Consider an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with sides $BC= 30, CA = AB = 20.$ Let $D$ be the foot of the perpendicular from A to $BC$, and let M be the midpoint of $AD.$ Let $PQ$ be a chord of the circumcircle of triangle $ABC,$ such that M lies on $PQ$ and $PQ$ is parallel to $BC.$ The length of $PQ$ is:

I used the power of point (intersecting chords) theorem to find this.
Any other ways in which it could be done?
The method which I used:


$TS=BC/2$ (Mid-point)

$TS=15$

$AS=SC=BT=TA=10\text{ cm}$ (Mid-point)

$PT=SQ=x$

$PT(TQ)=BT(TA)$ (Intersecting Chords Theorem)


So, you get: $$x^2+15x-100$$
Solving which, gives you the value of $x$. Then, just add $2x$ to $15$ and you get the answer: $25$

Have you tried solving it?

Yes, I am just searching for another way

Please add your method and solution in the question, it helps others from avoiding that specific method

$$\text{Circumradius} \ R=\frac{\text{Product of sides}}{\text{4×Area}}=\frac{40}{\sqrt 7}$$
As the triangle is isoceles, the circumcentre is collinear to $A$ and $D$. It lies outside the triangle as $AD=5\sqrt 7<R$. Then
$$PQ=2\sqrt{R^2-\bigg(R-\frac{AD}{2}\bigg)^2}=25$$ using Pythagoras' theorem

Thanks for the response

@SubhayanChakraborty  :)
